# Sharepoint 2010 document is not being hard deleted

Tags: 2010, delete

There are some documents in our content database that need to be hard deleted.

I've logged into as a site admin and using the interface gone and deleted them and even deleted it from the recycle bin.

However, when I navigate to the AllDoc and AllDocStreams table they still exist.

Do I have to do this manually? And if so, do I just need to delete the row from the AllDocs and AllDocStreams table?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete it from content database directly. It is not supported action and you will break the agreement of service.

Please make sure you delete the item from both recycle bins(1st stage and 2nd stage). Once it gone from 2nd stage recycle bin then it will be flush from content database. But if you still seeing it, wait for recycle bin timer job. Once it run successful then it should not be in content db.